# Unarchiving - iOS Swift - Can't get new method going

Tags: ios, swift, archive, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I've previously used `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData` to unarchive data that I've previously archived and stored in a data model.

I'm now trying to switch from `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData` to `.unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)` as `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData` is deprecated.

I've tried an absolute pile of attempts to get this to work and I feel I've just gotten further and further away from working code.

Below is my original code to archive and unarchive. Could someone please show me what needs to be done for the conversion to the new method?

Thanks.

Archiving code:

```
var selectedAmenities = [String: String]()

var archivedAmenities: Data!
do {
    archivedAmenities = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: selectedAmenities, requiringSecureCoding: false)
} catch {
    print("Couldn't archive the Amenities.")
}
```

Unarchiving code:

```
var selectedAmenities = [String: String]()

do {
    let unArchivedAmenities = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(theSite.amenities!)
    selectedAmenities = unArchivedAmenities as! [String: String]
} catch {
    print("Couldn't unarchive the Amenities.")
```

Comment: What's your error, exactly?

Comment: Specifically, if you log `error` inside of your `catch` block, what do you see?

Comment: The WWDC18 [Data You Can Trust](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2018/222krhixqaeggyrn33/222/222_hd_data_you_can_trust.mp4) talk is likely instructive; slides are available [as a PDF](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2018/222krhixqaeggyrn33/222/222_data_you_can_trust.pdf)

Comment: Problem is, I've tried so many different things, I don't have a particular error. I don't even really know where to start anymore. I guess I'll watch the Data You Can Trust and see what happens.

Comment: To be clear, this code works just fine. But it’s deprecated and I have no idea how to get the proper method working from this original code.

Comment: The non-deprecated alternatives to `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData` are [`unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2983380-unarchivedobject)/[`unarchivedObject(ofClasses:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2963379-unarchivedobject), passing in the type or types you expect to decode at that top level, but there's also [`unarchivedDictionary(ofKeyClass:objectClass:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/3650110-unarchiveddictionary)

Comment: Given that `selectedAmenities` is a `[String: String]`, you can try to use that latter method, passing in `NSString.self` as both the key and object class (since `String` is a Swift struct, and `NSString` is the "equivalent" Obj-C class), then `as`-casting to `[String: String]`. If you attempt that, what results do you see?

Comment: (FWIW, `unarchivedDictionary(...)` is effectively a shortcut for `unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSDictionary, <key class>, <object class>], from: ...) as! [<key class>: <object class>]`)

Comment: Woo hoo! let unArchivedAmenities = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedDictionary(ofKeyClass: NSString.self, objectClass: NSString.self, from: theSite.amenities!) as [String: String]? That was the ticket @ItaiFerber Thanks!